# Deploy a Python code to Google cloud that updates table in cloud sql for mysql

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mysql-python, google-cloud-sql

I have written python code to get data from firebase(which is in json tree format) and convert it to mysql database on my local machine. I want to deploy this code on google cloud such that it does the same thing every hour and and saves/updates the database on cloud sql for mysql. Can you please help me with some hint of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a serverless enviroment (such as Google App Engine, Cloud Functions, or Cloud Run) to host your code and then use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/) to trigger it periodically.

Here are some useful docs to get your started:

- [Connecting to Cloud SQL from Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-run)
- [Using Cloud Scheduler with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/using-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow normally.

Having said that, I'm working up a blog series which will probably help you: https://medium.com/google-cloud/connecting-google-cloud-sql-94025ba27071

I've covered several of the common ways to connect to Cloud SQL and over time I'll be adding more and more ways/scenarios. Links to the first three detailed how-to guides are in that first post which should help get you up and running.